What to do with serial upvotes?
I noticed that someone is upvoting a relatively large bunch of my answers for the second day in a row. The system tracks it down and removes the rep, so no worries on that front, but still I would like to bring this to the attention of more experienced CogSci'ers or a mod and see what can be done. 

I am that person on this occasion. 
I tend to keep a close eye on new questions and make a good effort to upvote good new questions. I also see the bad answers that people flag. 
However,  I often find it difficult to keep up with reading answers as they sometimes get lost on the front page. I've also been quite busy with others things lately. So I have not been keeping up with people posting good answers over the last few months. 
However, I noticed that a few people have started posting some high quality answers (including yourself). So I've gone through and read some of their other answers. Where I felt that the answer was worthy of an upvote, I have upvoted the answer. So from my perspective, there's nothing sinister about it. It's just me efficiently allocating my reading time to identify good answers worthy of upvoting. Importantly, for every upvote, I read the answer and made a decision about whether I felt like it was worth an upvote. If I'd seen the answer earlier I would have upvoted it then.
From looking at the typical amount of votes you receive per answer, I think others agree that you are writing good answers.
Thanks for letting me know that the system removes this rep. It looks like I'll have to find another way of keeping track of good new answers.
Update: This whole situation prompted me to see how to more effectively keep track of new answers on the site. I see that searching for is:answer and sorting by newest provides a list of most recent answers. I've bookmarked it so I can more easily keep up with what are thew new interesting answers on the site.

I am more than honored for your words. After reading your motivations and thoughts I more than regret the automated deletion of your work. I do try to write decent answers, but often doubt the value of them. Your answer is certainly a big encouragement and even after deletion of the rep by your upvotes this is still a substantial and important motivation to keep on doing what I do. Many thanks.

Jeromy, you're our rock.

If you have a concern, you can flag one of your answers for moderator attention. But there's no need to, the system will take care of this automatically as you said.
See: What is serial voting and how does it affect me?
What if I think I'm the victim of voting fraud?

If the voting fraud is in the progress of happening or just happened
  recently, don't worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours
  after noticing before becoming concerned. The system should detect it
  and reverse it for you. Please do not try to get help on this issue on
  meta or by flagging for a moderator. All they will do is tell you to
  wait for the voting fraud script to run (they won't run it for you
  just this once).
If the 24 hours has already passed and the suspicious votes have not
  been reversed, you can then flag one of your posts and explain what
  happened so a moderator can look into it. It is generally preferred
  that you avoid asking about them on a site's Meta since details of the
  investigation cannot be divulged and you won't actually get any
  information that will be useful to other members of the community.

Moderators cannot see votes cast by users. What we do have is access to the ♦ moderator tools which provide vote anomaly reports. Often these are not useful and not actionable. After reviewing this case I personally believe you've just been posting good answers and so a user was upvoting your content. I am sure the user in question was not malicious and I know the user in question understand how the system works. The automatic system just decided it was serial upvoting.

Thanks @JoshGitlin. I was just wondering if there's a possibility to track this person down and engage in a chat. Probably not :)

I'm looking at moderator tools now. I see what's happening (and laughed out loud) and will contact the user.
